# Плеер для интернет-радио

Tags: c++, c#

Хотел бы написать свой плеер, который воспроизводит потоки интернет-радиостанций. Язык: C# либо C++. Подскажите, с чего начать, какие библиотеки порекомендуете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рекомендую библиотеку [Bass](http://www.un4seen.com/) (бесплатно для некоммерческого использования). Есть привязки на C/C++, .NET. Достаточно много примеров, в частности для shoutcast (это интернет радио).